# run .jar on .app bundle with arguments

Tags: java, macos, executable-jar, automator

I created a .app bundle that executes jar file. I made the app bundle the default application for a specific file type. how to pass the selected file as argument to the java program

the script that I am using:

```
on run (input, parameters) 
  set p to POSIX path of (path to me) 
  do shell script java -jar" & p & "/Contents/Java/MyFile.jar' 
end run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "selection" to get the path of the selected file, and use POSIX to get the right representation:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set filePath to POSIX path of (selection as text)
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You OS should pass the file names as individual command line arguments. That means you get them as elements in the parameter of

```
public void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: @W.N Java has no main *function*. Java has a main *method* which is exactly the signature i posted.

Comment: yes sorry my bad, no argument are captured by main method. actually the script does not pass any argument, my question is how to know the double-clicked file and pass its path to the java program, please check the script that I use on the automator when I created the .app bundle

Comment: @W.N *"actually the script does not pass any argument,..."* this means the problem is the scripting language and and how your OS handles file selections and starting programs and has nothing to do with java in particular. You might consider changing the category tags...